# c# progressbar update according to file send progress

Tags: c#, sockets, progress-bar

i send a file converted to byte on a socket. and i want to update the current sending status(somthing similar when using weboscket and downloading somthing from the web).

this is the send code:

```
byte[] arr = File.ReadAllBytes(file); //sending simple text file.
 s.Send(data); //s is a socket of course.
```

now of course i cant do this

```
s.Send(data);
 progressBar1.Value=100;//show completed progress after sucesufully send.
```

but i want to do it while sending the file.. and update it according to the fil state... lets say if its 100kb file so every 1kb sent to update it.. im aware im sending the whole file at once and not parts of it but still... is there any way for that?

Comment: `Socket.Send` does not give progress updates so its difficult to do without breaking it up yourself. Even the async methods don't give feedback. Even if you broke it up, the Nagle algorithm may end up combining your packets with other network traffic and will skew your progress calculation. The only easy way to do this is to send the data as a stream and update as you write to that stream, of course that only works with TCP traffic though...

Comment: @RonBeyer how's `Stream.Write() ` different? from that method you can get a index about the progress?

Comment: Why don't you send each time part of the data? And update the bar after each send

Comment: @itapi its not different and no you can't get an index, but you can make buffered writes to it until all the data you want to send is sent. It has the same problems with the Nagle algorithm though (unless its disabled) and I don't know if stream buffers to the packet size before completing a send, or if it sends each time you write, I'd have to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Socket.Send` is blocking until all data in the `byte[]` is sent. So you will not get any chance to update a progress bar unless you do multiple sends of small chunks of data until the whole amount of data is transmitted.

If you want reliable communication, you need to use TCP/IP. The default maximum packet size of TCP/IP is around 1500 bytes ('MTU'). The exact value depends on your computer's network settings. If you split your data, I suggest you do it into multiple of the MTU size, so that you will have no half packets.
But if you're really transmitting over a network, I wonder why you are going to implement a progress bar for sending 100kB over a network that is capable of transmitting 100Mbit/s or even 1000MBit/s... Your data will be sent before the UI even has a chance to update the progress bar. This is only interesting for medium sized or large data of >> 1MB.

Enhancement:
See [MSDN Socket.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w93yy28a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details. Read especially the notes on that page:

> The successful completion of a send does not indicate that the data was successfully delivered.

because it means that the data was only successfully stored in the output buffer. If you really want to know that the data has arrived, you should design your opponent to send a reply after each (n) packet(s).

Comment: allright i understand. but one thing-what did you mean in this sentence here ` But if you're really transmitting over a network,` of course i do want it? that's the use of socket no? @TobiasKnauss

Comment: Yes, it is. So it means that I am actually querying the use of your progress bar.